# Turn all right clicks on site into left clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a quick JavaScript fix:

Assume you are browsing a single webpage on a device with a mouse or trackpad (PC/Laptop) and I want following to happen.

When you right click the mouse:

- Deactivate the right click. So no dropdown menu.
- Turn the right click to a left click, e.g. I've clicked the right mouse button over an image or anchor, the site should handle it as if I've clicked with the left mouse button on this element.

This function should work on the whole website, on all elements.
Is there an easy way to fix this issue?

I've already tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function click (e) {
  if (!e)
    e = window.event;
  if ((e.type && e.type == "contextmenu") || (e.button && e.button == 2) || (e.which && e.which == 3)) {
    if (window.opera)
      window.alert("Sorry, this function is deactivated.");

    return false;
  }
}
if (document.layers)
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown = click;
document.oncontextmenu = click;
clickedOption.parentNode.selectedIndex = clickedOption.index;
</script>
```

This disables the function of the right mouse click but I can't get it to behave like a left mouse click.
Any solutions? What might be wrong?

Comment: There’s no `e.preventDefault();` in the `click` function…

Comment: @A.Wolff You mean `return false`.

Comment: @Xufox `return false;` which is a shorthand for `event.preventDefault()` & `event.stopPropagation();` in jQuery

Comment: You can simulatethe actions that come with a left click from jquery via the event handler, just note that you can't simulate a left-click as a native event on elements in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will force a left click on right clicks on the document, or any elements you click

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){

  // Stop the context menu
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  // Try to avoid document wide things, just elements
  if(e.target.nodeName != 'HTML'){
    e.target.click();      
  }
});

// Testing
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.target.innerHTML = 'Caught';
});
```

```html
<div>Right Click Me</div>
<span>Right Click Me</span>
```

---

---

To answer the comment to my answer ->

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){

  // Stop the context menu
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
        
  
});

// Testing
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.target.innerHTML = 'Caught';
});
```

```html
<div>I dont work on right clicks</div>
```

Comment: Note that the `click` event is going to be triggered for left *and* right clicks anyway. So in this particular case you end up running the onclick code twice.

Comment: No, it does not. I added a snippet to my code to show you that it does not

Comment: Thanks for that, it works perfect! Last problem: When I click on a hyperlink with a right click, the browser alerts the user "Popup blocked". The link is target: "_blank" and this does not happen when I click with the left mouse button?

Comment: @Jesse Thank you, appreciating it!

Answer (score 2):

You could dispatch click event on document mousedown if right button is pressed:

```
$(document).on('mousedown contextmenu', function (e) {
    if (e.button === 2) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var mclick = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        mclick.initMouseEvent("click", false, true, window, 0, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
        e.target.dispatchEvent(mclick);
    }
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Not sure it will fit all your needs but i guess give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$("body").on("contextmenu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
});
```